# Mac上でのISOイメージを用いたCentOSインストールDVD作成方法

Tags: linux, macos, centos

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

DVD-RにCentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1804.isoを焼きました。
開きたいのですが、「マウントできるファイルシステムがありません」と
表示されます。

試した事
(1)DiskImageMounterを使って開く
(2)ディスクユーティリティでMacintosh HDをFirst Aidを実行

どのようにすれば開けますでしょうか。
また、DVD0956にCent0S7~.isoのイメージファイルの書き込みは成功はしていますよね？

お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 先の質問のコメントに書きましたが、そのisoファイルはmacOSでマウントできる形式にはなっていません。DVDへの焼き込み方が正しいかどうかによらず、macOS標準ではマウントできません。

Comment: macOSでは打つ手なしという事でしょうか？

Comment: あまり時間をとったわけじゃないですが、私にはiso形式のLinuxインストールディスクをmacOS上にマウントする方法は見つけられませんでした。(何かのフリーソフト入れればなんとかなるかと思ったのですが、短時間では見つけられず。)ちなみに正しくDVDに書き込めている場合、そのDVDはmacOSではマウントできず、当然中のファイルを見ることもできません。DVDがマウントできて「〜.iso」ファイルが1個見えている状態というのは、正しくDVDが焼けた状態になってないですね。

Comment: 私の場合、マウントできるできるファイルシステムがありませんがありませんと表示され、CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1804.isoファイルが1個見えている状態なので、書き込みに失敗しているという事でしょうか。

Comment: 「CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1804.isoファイルが1個見えている状態」と言うのは間違っていると思ってください。例えばmac用のisoファイル手に入れてうまく焼けたら、そのディスクを開いて見えるのは、isoファイルそのものではなく、isoファイルの中にアーカイブされた元のmacファイル群になります。

Comment: 1. 焼いたDVDの中にISOイメージ1つだけがある状態は「間違っている」 / 2. インストールDVDを作成するだけならmacでマウントする必要が無い / 3. 正常に焼けたかはとりあえずインストール対象のPCでブートを試すのが手っ取り早い

Comment: https://nt-take.com/2017/12/11/post-351/ と全く同じやり方で書き込み、そしてDVDの中にISOイメージが1つ"だけ"ではない事が確認出来たら、用意している物理マシンにDVDを挿入して見ます。

Comment: 「そしてDVDの中にISOイメージが1つ"だけ"ではない事が確認」の部分は「macでは書き込み後のDVDがマウントできないので中身が全く確認できない」(多分すぐイジェクトされます)で構わないのだということをお忘れなく。

Comment: つまりインストール対象の物理マシンでブートしてみないと、macOS上ではISOイメージが1つ"だけ"ではない事を確認をしたくても出来ないという事でしょうか？

Comment: そういうことです。mac上で今回のようなISOイメージがうまく焼けたかどうかを確認することはできません。

Comment: 理解できました。成功するまで焼く→物理マシンにブートを試してみます。

Comment: ちなみに、MACでISOファイルをDVDに書き込むには、ディスクユーティリティなどは使わずに焼けます。　書き込みたいISOファイルを右クリックすると、”ディスクイメージ〜〜をディスクに書き込む”とメニューが表示されるので、クリックしてDVDなどに書き込みます。

Comment: yyzさん ありがとうございます。「ディスクイメージ"CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1804.iso"をディスクに書き込む」で作成しました